# Trying to import Issues from JIRA to Redmine

Tags: migration, jira, integration, redmine

Following this: https://www.redmine.org/issues/1385#note-43

I have been trying to run the following query: **rake jira_migration:test_all_migrations RAILS_ENV=production**
And below mentioned is the trace:
rake jira_migration:test_all_migrations RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- config/environment
C:/xampp/htdocs/redmine-4.1.1/lib/tasks/migrate_jira.rake:4:in `require' C:/xampp/htdocs/redmine-4.1.1/lib/tasks/migrate_jira.rake:4:in` <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in` block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `each' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in` run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in` load_tasks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in` method_missing'
C:/xampp/htdocs/redmine-4.1.1/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in` load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in` raw_load_rakefile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in` standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in` block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in` run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>' C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in` load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in `'

Answer (score 0):

Followed these steps through the link posted in the question:

1. Go to Jira Administration -> Import & Export -> Backup Data to XML (*) * It's possible you have to configure a Backup Dir In the file:
   /usr/local/jira/atlassian-jira-enterprise-4.1.2-standalone/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/jira-application.properties
   For example adding this line: jira.paths.safe.backup.path=/tmp
2. Save the backup with the name: backup_jira.xml
3. Put this file in the main dir of redmine. In my case: /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2
4. Download the script "migrate_jira.rake" developed by Luciano Pacheco: http://www.redmine.org/attachments/download/6106/migrate_jira.rake
5. Put the script in the [redmine dir]/lib/tasks/. In my case: /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2/lib/tasks/
6. Now: cd /usr/local/lib/redmine-1.2
7. And: rake jira_migration:test_all_migrations RAILS_ENV="production"
   Before this command we are getting a file called "map_jira_to_redmine.yml"
8. Edit this file with the editor you want (vi, pico, nano...). For instance: pico map_jira_to_redmine.yml
9. This file contains the priorities, types and status of your Jira Projects. On the left side Jira Features, On the right side Redmine Features. You can adjust your Redmine, for example the trackers in the Administration web section to link exactly with the features of your Jira Projects. You can do it the same process with the states and priorities.
10. Once you set this file. You only have to run this: rake jira_migration:do_all_migrations RAILS_ENV="production"

Comment: this helped me a lot but I stuck on point 9, can you please provide me format for map_jira_to_redmine.yml. I got empty file like

 `types: {}
status: {}
priorities: {}
`

Comment: i don't have that 'Import & Export' section, so i prefer to use any API  client with any well known language. documentation: `https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/`